# Xamarin.Forms downgrade package issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I'm using **Xamarin.Forms**. I **updated all Xamarin.Android.Support** package in my VS project. So when I realize updating Xamarin.Android.Support package in Xamarin.Forms is a mistake, I remove all package and install Xamarin.Forms last version and let it to install the dependencies in other word downgrade the dependencies to 23.3.0 version. So now, when I clean and rebuild my solution I get this error.

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   ....\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.targets.

I think we should not install this package manually. Xamarin.Forms should take care of the dependencies. All dependencies is in 23.3.0 version and it is clear that no need to install Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.25.4.0.2 manually.

So what should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: what happens if you restore nuget packages , also try clean -> build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved. The package CarouselView.FormsPlugin new version (4.4.3) has dependency to Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 version 24.2.1 (Android 7).
Downgrade to version 4.4.2 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms locks in a very specific version of the support libraries and google play services. You can't update them because Xamarin.Forms isn't compatible with them as it would need to be re-compiled.

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.0.1.3)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.0.1.3)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.0.1.3)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.0.1.3)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.0.1.3)
```

See the = `23.0.1.3`, which means it is only compatible with that version number. This is just how NuGet works. When Xamarin.Forms updates these packages will auto update.

When you want to update Xamarin.Forms ONLY update Xamarin.Forms, don't update all of the packages. When you update just Xamarin.Forms it will update it's dependencies to the correct version number needed.

If you already update the other nugets that aren't letting you update, you could simply uninstall your packages and re-install just Xamarin.Forms.

Here is a video: http://screencast.com/t/U5FBj6KlH